# kernel function to get the container pointer when given a pointer to a member that is a pointer type itself?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am trying to access a structure container when given a member pointer which is a pointer type itself. container_of() does not work in this case and I have to manually calculate the offset then calculate the container address myself. Is there any kernel function I can call that is similar to container_of() but take care of this case?

For example in below code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({                      \
        const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);    \
        (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})

typedef struct A
{
    int filler;
    int *data;
}A;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    A *a = malloc(sizeof(A));
    a->data = malloc(sizeof(int));

    printf("1st part: use container_of():\n");
    printf("a: %p | a->data: %p\n", a, a->data);
    int *member_ptr = a->data;
    A *c = container_of(member_ptr, A, data);
    printf("c: %p\n", c);

    printf("2nd part: manually calculate offset: \n");
    unsigned long offset = (unsigned long)(&(((A*)0)->data));
    printf("a: %p | &(a->data): %p | offset: 0x%x | &(a->data) - offset: %p", a, &(a->data), offset, (unsigned long)(&(a->data)) - offset);

    free(a->data);
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

The first part pointer c is NOT equal to a when using container_of():

```
Use container_of():
a: 0x166d260 | a->data: 0x166d280
c: 0x166d278
```

The 2nd part works fine tho

```
Manually calculate offset: 
a: 0x166d260 | &(a->data): 0x166d268 | offset: 0x8 | &(a->data) - offset: 0x166d260
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're quite obviously using it wrong and that's why gcc is (should be) giving you an `incompatible-pointer-types` warning.

It should be

```
A *c = container_of(&a->data, A, data);
```

NOT

```
A *c = container_of(a->data, A, data);
```

There is absolutely *no* relationship between the `a->data` value and the address of `a`.

(Piece of advice: heed the warnings (or compile with `-Werror` so you have no choice but to)).

Comment: Awesome! thanks for pointing that out. It works like a charm now